# Is there a better way of linking transitions in Corona Lua?

Tags: animation, lua, coronasdk

I'm currently animating a trash can when something gets dragged and dropped onto it with this code:

```
local trashUp
local trashDown

trashUp = function()
    transition.to(
    trash, {time=100, xScale=1.2, yScale=1.2, onComplete=trashDown })
end

trashDown = function()
    transition.to(
    trash, {time=100, xScale=1, yScale=1})
end
```

and then calling trashUp() when I want to start the animation.

The code works fine, but I can't help feel it could be coded better. Two functions to animate an object!

Is there any way I can do this more efficiently?

Comment: What is inefficient about this code, specifically?

Comment: I think the question is about ugliness rather than inefficiency.

Comment: Yeah. I guess it's not efficiency, it's more that I'm having to create and call two functions to do something pretty basic. I wondered if there was a tidier way of doing it.

Comment: use an appropriate easing function. see answer below

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do it in a single function by setting the second transition with delay; refer to this code example: http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/transitionto

Depending on your situation however that's not necessarily less complicated, because now you have to keep track of two transitions simultaneously instead of just one transition at a time. In the code you posted you aren't keeping track of the transitions, but you probably should be in case you need to cancel them before the transition is complete (eg. the player switches scenes in the middle of the transition).

Comment: Thank, yeah, I did try that but I couldn't seem to get it to work. Now I'm going to have to research "keeping track of transitions"!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by coding the `onComplete` function inline with the first transition call:

```
animateTrash = function()
    transition.to(
        trash,
        { time=100, xScale=1.2, yScale=1.2, onComplete=
            function()
                transition.to(
                    trash,
                    {time=100, xScale=1, yScale=1})
            end
        })
end
```

This won't be any more ***efficient***, but it does keep everything to do with animating the trashcan in one place.  I think this approach could get quickly out of hand, though, especially if you were doing anything other than the transitions when animating the trashcan, e.g., updating your program's state, or creating/destroying other objects, etc.

Echoing jhocking's answer, this approach doesn't support canceling either.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I still need to use two functions tho? Maybe I'm not as far off as I thought…

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but since I was trying to do the same thing, I figured I should share what I came up with. This sequentially executes transitions that are passed in as variable args. If onComplete is supplied, it is called as its transition completes.

```
local function transitionSequence(target, step, ...)
  local remaining_steps = {...}
  if #remaining_steps > 0 then
    local originalOnComplete = step.onComplete
    step.onComplete = function(target)
      if originalOnComplete then
        originalOnComplete(target)
      end
      transitionSequence(target, unpack(remaining_steps))
    end
    transition.to(target, step)
  else
    transition.to(target, step)
  end
end
```

Example:

```
transitionSequence(myImage,
  {xScale=0.5, onComplete=function(t) print("squeeze") end},
  {xScale=1, onComplete=function(t) print("relax") end},
  {yScale=2, onComplete=function(t) print("stretch") end},
  {yScale=1, onComplete=function(t) print("relax again") end})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
transition.to( trash, {time=t, delta=true, xScale=1.5, transition=easing.continousLoop} )
```

Also very useful for purposes like that:

```
easing.sin = function( f, a )
  return function(t, tmax, start, d)
    return start + delta + a*math.sin( (t/tmax) *f * math.pi*2 )
  end
end

easing.sinDampened = function( f, a, damp )
  return function(t, tmax, start, d)
    return start + delta + a*math.sin( damp^(t/tmax) *f * math.pi*2 )
  end
end
```

...etc